# I see non-existing remote branches and what does git remote prune origin do in that case?

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I do:

```
$ git branch -a
  feature/XXX-5793
  feature/XXX-6864
  feature/XXX-7534
  feature/XXX-9067
  feature/XXX-9204
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/feature/BIOVK-13
  remotes/origin/feature/XXX-11313
  remotes/origin/feature/XXX-11481
  remotes/origin/feature/XXX-3311
  remotes/origin/feature/XXX-5793
  remotes/origin/feature/XXX-6448
  remotes/origin/feature/XXX-7237
  remotes/origin/feature/XXX-7534
  remotes/origin/feature/XXX-9067
  remotes/origin/feature/XXX-9204
  remotes/origin/master
```

My first question is: in the remotes/origin list there are branches which are not on our bitbucket server anymore. How can that be?

After this I did:

```
$ git remote prune origin
Pruning origin
URL: ...
 * [pruned] origin/feature/XXX-11481
 * [pruned] origin/feature/XXX-3311
 * [pruned] origin/feature/XXX-5793
 * [pruned] origin/feature/XXX-6448
 * [pruned] origin/feature/XXX-7237
 * [pruned] origin/feature/XXX-9067
 * [pruned] origin/feature/XXX-9204
```

My second question is: I thought: git remote prune origin removes local branches which are remote not there anymore. But here my list of remote branches is cleared.

Later I removed the local branches with git branch -d, so the result became:

```
$ git branch -a
  feature/XXX-7534
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/feature/XXX-11313
  remotes/origin/feature/XXX-7534
  remotes/origin/master
```

Answer (score 1):

git is designed to be both fully decentralised, and usable without an always-on internet connection, so very few commands actually contact a remote server.

Without contacting the Bitbucket server, git can't know which branches actually still exist. So what are the branch names you saw, and which were "pruned" when you asked?

If you look at [the description of `git remote prune` in the manual](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote), you'll see this:

> By default, stale remote-tracking branches under <name> are deleted

What's basically going on here is that when you *do* fetch data from the remote server, git caches that in the form of "remote-tracking branches". These act sort of like normal branches, but are actually just a marker saying "last time we talked to the remote server, there was a branch with this name and this tip commit".

These pointers are *completely separate* from *local* branches you may have created with the same name: you might have a local "master", an "origin/master" referring to one remote server, and a "joebloggs/master" referring to a different remote server. Meanwhile, the *actual* remote servers might have new commits on master, or have deleted it completely, but your internet is unplugged so you have no way of knowing.

This lets you run commands like `git diff master origin/master` which compares your local branch named "master" against the remote branch "master" *based on the most recent cache you have of the remote branch*.

By default (without the `--prune` option), running `git fetch` will create and update these pointers, but never delete them - if no branch of that name is there on the remote server, the local pointer will just be left wherever it was last seen. These are the "stale remote-tracking branches" the manual is talking about: a cache of something that *used to* exist on the remote server, but doesn't any more.